# Regular expression to fetch mobile number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to fetch contact number from a string like "+19876543210 (mobile)" using below regex and its working fine for almost all format of number but not if number is starting with zero

```
var contact = "+19876543210 (mobile)"; 
// If var contact = "09876543219 then its not working"    
contact.match(/^(\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-.\s]?\(?[1-9]\d{2}\)?[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}/)
```

Comment: No it's not, number you are trying is of 11 digit including zero, well I am sooooo stupid, I should provide the range from 0-9 instead of 1-9

Comment: Your question, your comment, your answer. Aur hum samjhe aapko humaari zaroorat hai. ;)

Comment: Hahahahahha sorry man, I found out just after posting this question. warna kabhi apko taklif nhi deta.. ;)

Comment: It's okay, man. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
/^(\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-.\s]?\(?[0-9]\d{2}\)?[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}/
```